# MySQL: Is There a way to dynamically generate multiple date range based on its date

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql, datetime

The data I got is

| id | date | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2021-11-26' | 1 |
| 1 | '2021-11-25' | 1 |
| 1 | '2021-11-24' | 1 |
| 1 | '2021-11-23' | 1 |

The result I want is

| id | from_date | to_date | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2021-11-23' | '2021-11-24' | 2 |
| 1 | '2021-11-23' | '2021-11-25' | 3 |
| 1 | '2021-11-23' | '2021-11-26' | 4 |
| 1 | '2021-11-24' | '2021-11-25' | 2 |
| 1 | '2021-11-24' | '2021-11-26' | 3 |
| 1 | '2021-11-25' | '2021-11-26' | 2 |

Is there a way to generate those dates (from_date, to_date) from the date column in the data?

Do I need to use loop from the iteration of the date?

What else I can think of to get close to the result?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to generate those dates (from_date, to_date)

A "triangular join":

```
SELECT a.date AS from_date,
       z.date AS to_date
    FROM t AS a
    CROSS JOIN t AS z
    WHERE a.date < z.date
```

That can then be joined again to `t` to deal with the sums.

Comment: That's more of a triangular join. You may as well use proper join syntax with an `ON` clause

Comment: Hmmm... I learned something new.  MySQL never mentions "triangular joins".

Comment: No it wouldn't there is no special syntax, just `JOIN t AS z ON a.date < z.date`

Comment: You saved my days! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a simple table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sample` (
    `id`            int(11)        UNSIGNED   NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date`          timestamp                 NOT NULL    ,
    `cnt`           int(11)        UNSIGNED   NOT NULL    DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

With data like this:

```
INSERT INTO `Sample` (`date`)
VALUES ('2021-11-26'),
       ('2021-11-25'),
       ('2021-11-24'),
       ('2021-11-23');
```

You can do this:

```
SELECT tmp.`id`,
       DATE_FORMAT(tmp.`from_dts`, '%Y-%m-%d') as `from_date`,
       DATE_FORMAT(tmp.`to_dts`, '%Y-%m-%d') as `to_date`,
       SUM(sm.`cnt`) as `cnt`
  FROM `Sample` sm INNER JOIN (SELECT a.`id`, DATE_FORMAT(a.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') as `from_dts`, DATE_FORMAT(z.`date`, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') as `to_dts`
                                 FROM `Sample` a INNER JOIN `Sample` z ON a.`date` < z.`date`) tmp ON sm.`date` BETWEEN tmp.`from_dts` AND tmp.`to_dts`
 GROUP BY tmp.`id`, `from_date`, `to_date`
 ORDER BY `from_date`, `to_date`;
```

There are certainly other ways to accomplish this same goal but, this will do in a pinch. If you are going to be running this sort of query against millions of records, though, you will want to approach the problem *very* differently.

Comment: Somehow the summed cnt shows more than I expected. but the range of the date were generated correctly.